# how to apply a class method to each value of an array?

Tags: php

I want to apply a class method `$this->escape($str)` to all the values of an `$data` array.

I know I can use PHP's `array_walk()` function to apply a `function` to each value of an array, but I want to apply a `class method`. Is this possible? If yes, then how?

Please give me the shortest possible code for this task, and I don't want to use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4):

Use `array($instance, 'methodName')` as the callback function.

When using PHP5.3 you could also pass an anonymous function calling the method: `function($value) { return $this->escape($value); }`

See <s>`http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback`</s>(dead link) for more information about callback types in PHP.

Comment: how can i apply `array($instance, 'methodName') as the callback function` to my array?

Comment: By passing it as an argument to `array_walk`: e.g. `array_walk($data, array($this, 'escape'));`

Comment: how to pass an argument too dude?

Comment: In this case you need to use the anonymous function - see the second code block in my answer. You can put arbitraty code in that function.

Comment: I'm getting this error, `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\apple\system\core\db.php on line 90` , and line number 90 = `$this->something = array_walk(array_keys($data), function($value) { return $this->escape($value); });`

Comment: Instead of `$this` you obviously need to use whatever variable your instance is stored in. But since you used `$this` in your question I assumed it's done inside a class... In case it is, try doing `$self = $this;` before the call and use `$self` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented here: http://nl.php.net/callback .